# How I replace these cases from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to replace from dictionary to number the following cases :

```
dic={
'TREINTA Y UNO':'31',
'TREINTA Y DOS':'32',
'TREINTA Y TRES':'33',
'TREINTA Y CUATRO':'34',
'TREINTA Y CINCO':'35',
'TREINTA Y SEIS':'36',
'TREINTA Y SIETE':'37',
'TREINTA Y OCHO':'38',
'TREINTA Y NUEVE':'39'}
```

tried this

```
sal = ' '.join([dic_letras.get(i, i) for i in v1.split()])
```

result: `'30 y 2'`

when I want the replacement to `32`

Comment: Of course.  You are splitting your text into words.  Therefore, you will never find a multi-word phrase.  You will either have to search for the phrases without splitting into words, or when you find "treinta", check if the next word is "y".

Comment: What's `v1`? Please provide a [mre]. You can [edit]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want to do here is to evaluate the text math expressions as arithmetic expressions.  One brute force approach would be to maintain a map of Spanish numbers and conjunctions to actual numbers and operators.  Then, use `eval()` on a list comprehension of the input expressions to generate math outputs.

```py
inp = ['TREINTA Y UNO', 'TREINTA Y DOS', 'TREINTA Y TRES', 'TREINTA Y CUATRO', 'TREINTA Y CINCO', 'TREINTA Y SEIS', 'TREINTA Y SIETE', 'TREINTA Y OCHO', 'TREINTA Y NUEVE']
dict = {'TREINTA': '30', 'UNO': '1', 'DOS': '2', 'TRES': '3', 'CUATRO': '4', 'CINCO': '5', 'SEIS': '6', 'SIETE': '7', 'OCHO': '8', 'NUEVE': '9', 'Y': '+'}
regex = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(dict.keys()) + r')\b'
output = [eval(re.sub(regex, lambda m: str(dict[m.group()]), x)) for x in inp]
print(output)  # [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
```

To be clear here, the first input `'TREINTA Y UNO'` as an example gets mapped to the string `'30 + 1'`.  We then evaluate this using `eval()` as 31.

Comment: I really doubt this is what OP wants to do. The solution to their problem seems to be just not to split the string into words.

Comment: @kaya3 I disagree: `when I want the replacement to 32` ... it seems my answer is precisely what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Your answer produces the expected result, but not from the OP's dictionary, which simply maps the string `'TREINTA Y DOS'` to `'32'`. For an input string of `'TREINTA Y DOS'`, a simple dictionary lookup is all that should be needed.

Comment: If the point of the question is how do we look up a key in a Python dictionary, then there is no actual question and it should be closed as a typo.  If there is a question here, I have answered it.

Comment: I agree, there is no actual question and the question should be closed.